# Macro VBA code runs fine when running independently but becomes broken when run in a string with other macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string of steps I turned into one macro. When run independently they are all fine but something happens on step 18 when it is run collectively that is causing a problem where the "place I am pasting to is not the same size as my copy". Can any of you help? My code should be okay as it behaves properly when I select step 18 specifically but I'm sure I'm doing something horribly wrong. This is my first time using VBA so anything helps! The goal of this is to filldown a vlookup statement to a dynamic range in columns P,Q, and R (Column R takes its values from another sheet within the workbook) The place it says it gets stuck on is:

```
"Range("P2:P" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll"
```

For reference here is the step before 18 and step 18's code:

```
Step 17:

Sub Step17_2()
'
' Step17_2 Macro
'

'
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:M").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub

Step 18:

Sub Step18()
'
' Step18 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Contact").Select
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "VlookupType"
    Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "VlookupIP"
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "VlookupMailingName"
    Range("P1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Dim LR As Integer
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,PastedValues!A$2:D$" & LR & ",2,FALSE)"
Range("P2").Copy
Range("P2:P" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("Q2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,PastedValues!A$2:D$" & LR & ",4,FALSE)"
Range("Q2").Copy
Range("Q2:Q" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("ContactDetailed").Select
Dim TA As Integer
TA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Contact").Select
Range("R2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,ContactDetailed!A$2:D$" & TA & ",4,FALSE)"
Range("R2").Copy
Range("R2:R" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: To begin with, you want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code. It is likely if you do, the problem will be fixed as the active cell is not always the one you think it is

Comment: And just `Range("P2:P" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,PastedValues!A$2:D$" & LR & ",2,FALSE)"` would do ;). And...dont use `Integers` is something I could recommend!

Comment: @JvdV thanks for your answer, I tried switching that out but it hits an error there as well. so now it is `Dim LR As Integer
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P2:P" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,PastedValues!A$2:D$" & LR & ",2,FALSE"
Application.CutCopyMode = False` error is from Range to end of VLookUp formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its some raw code you have there, some tips:

- Try and avoid the use of `.Select`, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) why and how.
- Don't use `Integer` variables. Why? Your data might at some point have more data an integer variable could store, namely `-32,768` to `32,767`. The use of `Long` or `Double` won't get you in future troubles.
- It's a good practice to store your variables at the start of your code, preferably using `Option Explicit`. That way you won't miss any undeclared variable.
- A lot of lines could actually be combined or are becomming useless when you would code straight in VBA instead of recording a macro.

Below is an example of how I would interpret your step 18:

```
Dim LR As Double, TA As Double

Option Explicit

Sub Step18()

TA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ContactDetailed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contact")
    .Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "VlookupType"
    .Range("Q1").FormulaR1C1 = "VlookupIP"
    .Range("R1").FormulaR1C1 = "VlookupMailingName"
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("P2:P" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,PastedValues!A$2:D$" & LR & ",2,FALSE)"
    .Range("Q2:Q" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,PastedValues!A$2:D$" & LR & ",4,FALSE)"
    .Range("R2:R" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,ContactDetailed!A$2:D$" & TA & ",4,FALSE)"
End With

End Sub
```

Also had a look at your step 17_2 and you could simplify that like this for example:

```
Sub Step17_2()

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contact") 'I assume you meant this sheet, change if need be
    .Range("C:C,E:N,P:AA").EntireColumn.Delete 'I used AA but you could also change this
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @JvdV that worked much faster! The only issue I am having is that the Vlookup is not grabbing from the correct table. Column P should grab from column two in the sheet named PastedValues, Column Q should grab from column 4 in the same sheet and Column R should grab from Column 4 in the sheet named ContactDetailed. I think it may be because of this piece: 

`Dim LR As Double, TA As Double

Option Explicit` 

It adds it to the end of step 17_2 rather than letting me claim those as variables.

Comment: Option explicit goes on top of your module, not a single macro. Variables declared above it. Look up an example on the internet.